# How to show that $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^2) = \mathbb{Z}_2$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

How to show that $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^2) = \mathbb{Z}_2$?

In general is well known that $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^n) = \mathbb{Z}_2, ~ n \ge 2.$

But how to show this assertion?

I have a few knowledge about covering spaces...

Comment: You have some knowledge of covering spaces, you say? Do you know what the universal covering space of the projective plane is?

Comment: @Arthur, know! I know nothing about universal covering.

Comment: Well it's going to be hard proving this without knowing anything about covering spaces. Don't put the cart before the horse...

Comment: Do you know how the cosets of $p_*(\pi_1(\tilde X,\tilde x_0))$ in $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ are related to the points in $p^{-1}(x_0)$ when $p: (\tilde X, \tilde x_0) \to (X,x_0)$ is a covering map and $\tilde X$ is path-connected?

Comment: yes! @StefanHamcke I know this

Comment: Then you should try to find a $2$-sheeted covering map $p: \tilde X \to RP^2$ with a simply-connected $\tilde X$. A simply-connected covering space is also called a *universal covering space*, so this is what I suppose Arthur was aiming at.

Comment: $S^n$ is then a universal covering for $\mathbb{RP}^n$.  In particular, $p^{-1}(x_0)$ is discrete and has two elements. Then for $n>2$, $S^n$ is simply connected. How to conclude???????? @StefanHamcke

Comment: Also for $n=2$, $S^n$ is simply-connected.

Comment: yes, @Stefan! But how to finish? How to conclude that the fundamental group is $Z_2?$

Comment: Since $p^{-1}(x_0)$ has two elements, $p_*(\pi_1(S^2))$ has two cosets in $\pi_1(RP^2)$. What does this mean for $\pi_1(RP^2)$?

Comment: thank you! Now it is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a covering map $p: Y \to X$, the induced map $p_*: \pi_1(Y) \to \pi_1(X)$ is injective, and the right cosets of $p_*(\pi_1(Y))$ in $\pi_1(X)$ are in bijection to the fiber $p^{-1}(x_0)$ if $Y$ is path-connected. The bijection is
$$
p_*(\pi_1(Y))a \mapsto \tilde a(1), \text{ where $a$ is a loop at $x_0$ and $\tilde a$ is its lift at $\tilde x_0$}
$$
(This assumes that the notation $ab$ means "*first the path a, then $b$*". If you use the reverse notation, you have to use the left cosets instead).

Now $p: S^2 \to RP^2$ is a $2$-sheeted covering map and $S^2$ is simply-connected. This means the image has two cosets in the fundamental group of $RP^2$, which is thus $Z_2$.

Answer (score 1):

For a "sufficiently nice" action of a group $G$ on a simply-connected, based space $X$, we can lift a loop $\gamma:[0, 1] \to G/X$ to a loop $\tilde \gamma$ in $G$. The map $\gamma \to \tilde \gamma(1)$ then induces a well-defined isomorphism $\pi_1(G/X) \to G$. In this particular case, "sufficiently nice" means "free and properly discontinuous," but you should really study covering spaces before computing $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP^2}) = \pi_1(S^2/\{\pm 1\})$; the proof of the statement above involves some technical lifting properties that are only a small step away from covering spaces anyway.

Comment: Well observed. Thanks for comment! +1